# Pdo Authentication

Tags: php, authentication, pdo

Ive written my PDO authentication which isnt complete i got this far and tested it i have debugged it and had no success finding the problem here.
This code should return invalid data except in this case it doesnt it goes to a blank page.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
require('.class/class_pdo.php');

$query = $db->prepare('SELECT player_login_name, player_login_pass FROM members
    WHERE player_login_name = :name AND player_login_pass = :pass');
$db->connect;
$query->bindParam(':name', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':pass', $pass, PDO::PARAM_STR);

$name = (isset($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['name'])) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']) : '';
$pass = (isset($_POST['pass']) && !empty($_POST['pass'])) ? password_verify($_POST['pass']) : '';

if($query->fetchColumn() == 0) {
    echo "Invalid data";
} else {
    header("location:'welcome.php'");
}
$query->execute();
?>
```

any ideas would be great thank you?

Comment: It seems that one single offtopic not-a-real-question can be just endless source of rep points. Every participant can take one single line of this randomly built code, fix it, and secure the deserved reward. Profit!

Comment: Then why don’t you vote to close it or answer it yourself, @YourCommonSense, instead of lambasting those that do take the time to answer.

Comment: @MartinBean Because Stack Overflow is a gamble where everyone is only after getting rep points. Means this question never gets closed (as there is no award for closures).

Comment: @YourCommonSense Well lead by example. If you don’t think this question fits Stack Overflow’s criteria, click the “Close” link above.

Comment: Are you redirected to `welcome.php`?

Comment: @MartinBean Well there are 100k+ questions led by example already, thank you.  And it is not "I think" but this question *is* offtopic. Care to read the rules?

Comment: Chanchal no not redirected

Comment: `header("location:welcome.php");` change this and redirected? remove single quotes around welcome.php

Comment: chanchal not working its ok thank you for your help ill recode it !!

Comment: Also you need to put `execute()` before `fetchColumn()` call.

Comment: How on earch `fetchColumn()` will return something valid before `execute()` is called?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have error here

```
password_verify($_POST['pass'])
```

The [`password_verify()`](http://www.php.net/function.password-verify) requires 2 parameters , but you are passing just one. It is missing the **hash** that is ought to be compared with.

Comment: this is not an answer, but comment. Please moderate your desire to rep points. *If* you decide to answer an offtopic question, make it complete answer, not just a comment on one minor issue.

Comment: @YourCommonSense,  I don't think this is a comment because this is first and foremost thing that is making the code not to execute (**As this is a syntactical error**) as he is not providing the `hash` to be compared with the password. Moreover, i can't find a single variable that refers to a hash.

Comment: Again. This doesn't solve the problem in the OP. Which is far from any code issue. If your answer doesn't answer the question but only outlines one single minor issue - it have to be comment. Isn't it clear enough?

Comment: Thank you this did help but not fixed the issue, thank you again